# Chaining Where Clauses Does Not Return Results

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have a search method that takes a list of ID's and I wish to restrict the query based on the ID's.

Param: IEnumerable filterType

```
foreach (int id in filterType)
{
    query = query.Where(q => q.Item1 == id);
}
```

If I try:

```
foreach (int id in filterType)
{
    query = query.Where(q => q.Item1 != id);
}
```

It seems to work.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple `where` clauses are effectively "AND-ed" together - so if your `filterType` list had 5 and 10 in, you'd be saying that `Item1` had to be both 5 *and* 10, which it can't be simultaneously.

I suspect you actually want:

```
query = query.Where(q => filterType.Contains(q.Item1));
```

In other words, where `Item1` matches *one of* the values in `filterType`. (You might also want to consider the case where `filterType` is empty. Should that match everything or nothing?)

Comment: Thanks for that it was really wrecking my head!

Answer (score 2):

By doing `query = query.Where(q => q.Item1 == id);`, you're effectively building a query similar to the following:

```
query.Where(q => q.Item1 == id1)
     .Where(q => q.Item1 == id2)
     .Where(q => q.Item1 == id3)
     .Where(q => q.Item1 == id4);
```

Which obviously won't return results: an item cannot have two different IDs.

You probably want:

```
query.Where(q = filterType.Contains(q.Item1));
```